# Filter duplicates of type Object from List in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, filter, duplicates, linkedhashmap

I got a LinkedHashMap that has some duplicates in the output. 
The map looks like this:

```
Map<Object, List<Object>> myMap= new LinkedHashMap<Object, List<Object>>();
```

When I sysout this map the result looks like this:

```
 Test.example.id   = [Source.table1.id, Source.table2.id], 
 Test.example.name = [Source.table1.name, Source.table1.name]
```

Now I'd like to filter out all the duplicates on a record so the output would be:

```
 Test.example.id   = [Source.table1.id, Source.table2.id], 
 Test.example.name = [Source.table1.name]
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Kevin

Comment: Is it necessary that your Map is of type Object? It looks like it could be a String or some numeric type?

Comment: The Map contains Objects from a custom class wich has several functions wich I use later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Java 8, you could do it like this (it modifies the map in place):

```
myMap.replaceAll((k, v) -> v.stream().distinct().collect(toList()));
```

Otherwise, you'd have to iterate over the values manually, put them into a `Set` to get the distinct property and then put them back in the map.

```
for(Map.Entry<Object, List<Object>> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
    myMap.put(entry.getKey(), new ArrayList<>(new HashSet<>(entry.getValue()))); //you can use a new map if you want to keep the original one
}
```

Comment: I can't use Java 8 in this project. I'm going to try your suggestion now, I'll get back to you. Thank you:)